# DocuSign Api creating envelope in Production

Tags: docusignapi

I have a problem with creating Envelope through the Api.

The authorization is performed without errors.

$options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi\LoginOptions();
$loginInformation = $authenticationApi->login($options);

I get this in response:

```
LoginInformation {
    #container: array:2 [
        "api_password" => null
        "login_accounts" => array:1 [
            0 => LoginAccount {
                #container: array:11 [
                    "account_id" => "xxxxx"
                    "account_id_guid" => null
                    "base_url" => "https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxx"
                    "email" => "xxxxx@xxxxxx.com"
                    "is_default" => "true"
                    "login_account_settings" => null
                    "login_user_settings" => null
                    "name" => "xxxxxxx, LLC"
                    "site_description" => ""
                    "user_id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    "user_name" => "xxxxxx Contracts Team"
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

But when I’m trying to create the Envelope this way:

$envelopeApi->createEnvelope($this->config->getAccountId(), $envelop_definition, $options);

I get this error: «[401] Error connecting to the API (https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxx/envelopes)”

This error notifies me that I’m not authorized. This code works properly in Sandbox.

I think that the problem is in settings of account - maybe there is a lack of special rights...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the right production platform. The right production platform is determined by the DocuSign Account ID.

See step 1 in the [Post Go Live](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/post-go-live) document.